# No permission to modify static procedure dynamic/1

Tags: prolog, prolog-directive-dynamic

```
dynamic( [im_at/1, door/1]).

im_at(car).

door(false).

/* Facts*/

path(car,forward,gasstation):-
   door(true),write('Wellcome to Gas Station'),nl,
   write('You can buy a newspaper or a drink!').
path(car,forward,gasstation):-
   write('You need to open the Car door '),nl,
   !,fail.
path(gasstation,back,car):-
   door(true),write('You got back in the car'),nl.
path(gasstation,back,car):-
   write('You need to open the car door'),nl.

open_cardoor:-
          door(true),
          write('You already opend the door!'),
          nl, !.
open_cardoor:-
    im_at(car),
    assertz(door(true)),
    retract(door(false)),nl,
    write('You openned the car door!'),nl,!.

forward:-go(forward).

back:-go(back).

go(Direction) :-
    im_at(Here),
    path(Here, Direction, There),
    retract(im_at(Here)),
    assert(im_at(There)),
    !.

buy(drink) :-
    im_at(gasstation),
    write('Added a drink to bag.'), nl,
    !.
buy(newspaper) :-
    im_at(gasstation),
    write('Added a newspaper to bag.'), nl,
    !.
buy(_):-
    write('You need to go to Gas Station to buy!'),nl.

start:- write('All that driving made me thirsty, you?'),nl.
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using SWI-Prolog. In order to declare a sequence of predicates dynamic, you should use the syntax [documented in the manual](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=declare). In your case, the correct clause is

```
:- dynamic im_at/1, door/1.
```

or

```
:- dynamic([im_at/1, door/1]).
```

The first line of your program attempts to *modify* the definition of [`dynamic/1`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=dynamic%2F1) by declaring that `dynamic([im_at/1, door/1])` is a *fact*. This is prohibited, because `dynamic/1` is [static](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=compile_predicates/1) (i.e., you are prohibited from modifying the definition of `dynamic/1` in a program).

Comment: writing `:- dynamic([im_at/1,door/1]).` as a declaration is fine.

Comment: @false Right. I wanted to stress the preferred syntax and highlight where the OP went wrong.

Comment: You are using a system that has `dynamic` defined as a prefix operator.

Comment: I believe the OP is using SWI-Prolog. In any case, updated to reflect your comment.